# How to find an erroneous statement in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyqt

In a PyQt application I receive this message:

> Could not parse stylesheet of object QLabel(0x560f3d6914e0)

How can I find the exact location of the relevant statement in Visual Studio Code as I do not know which label it is?

Comment: Is there no exception traceback?

Answer (score 0):

The number you see is the memory address for the widget within the Qt space, and that error is just shown in the stdout, so it cannot be directly debugged nor referenced.

In order to get the python object, you would need to wrap its instance using the functions provided by the sip module.

Unfortunately, since that error is given at runtime, you cannot "hardcode" it and convert later, since memory addresses are not persistent.

What you can do, though, is to run the code in an interactive python shell, and also import the `sip` module, then use [`wrapinstance()`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/sip/sip-module.html#PyQt5.sip.wrapinstance):

```py
>>> import MyProgram
>>> window = MyWindow()
# the error will probably appear here
Could not parse stylesheet of object QLabel(0x560f3d6914e0)

>>> import sip
>>> label = sip.wrapinstance(0x560f3d6914e0, QWidget)
>>> if label: print(label.objectName(), label.text(), label.styleSheet())
```

Alternatively, just add a temporary function that you can activate from a keyboard shortcut or button within your program (or even call it with QTimer) and use QInputDialog functions to do something similar to the above.

```py
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.showDebug)

    def showDebug(self):
        index, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Wrap label', 'Type the id')
        if ok:
            label = sip.wrapinstance(int(index, base=16), QWidget)
            if label:
                print(label.objectName(), label.text(), label.styleSheet())
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for caring about my problem. I have some trouble implementing you first proposal. My app has many modules and the main module launches a MainWindow that has many menu actions that trigger the appearance of dialogs. When I use >>>>import Main (my main module) this launches my app and I have no longer the possibility of entering commands. If my first command >>>from MainWindow improt MainWindow the app starts , I still have the prompt but I don't know how to trigger an action.

Comment: You are probably not using the conventional `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, which is important also for these scenarios. For future reference, please don't add a new answer that is fundamentally identical to an existing one if you just need to make small modifications: instead, notify their authors about the typos/improvements or suggest an edit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to musicamante I could manage to implement the second solution that required some little corrections:

```
from PyQt6 import sip
    def __init__(self, id,recipe_id,parent=None):
        ...
        
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.showDebug)

    def showDebug(self):
        index, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Wrap label', 'Type the id')
        if ok:
            label = sip.wrapinstance(int(index,base=16), QWidget)
            if label:
                print(label.objectName(), label.text(), label.styleSheet())
```

But it only returned me the label.styleSheet probably due to the fact the error was in an imported module.